# The connection to the server xxxx:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes

I follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) to install kubernetes on my cloud. 
When I run command `kubectl get nodes` I get this error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you at least connect to the service? `telnet localhost 6443`

Comment: @Lester yes. I can

Answer (score 2):

If you followed only mentioned docs it means that you have only installed `kubeadm`, `kubectl` and `kubelet`.

If you want to run `kubeadm` properly you need to do 3 steps more.

**1. Install docker**

Install [Docker ubuntu version](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). If you are using another system chose it from left menu side.

**Why:**

If you will not install docker you will receive errror like below:

```
preflight] WARNING: Couldn't create the interface used for talking to the container runtime: docker is required for container runtime: exec: "docker": e
xecutable file not found in $PATH
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip_forward]: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

**2. Initialization of `kubeadm`**

You have installed properly `kubeadm` and `docker` but now you need to initialize `kubeadm`. Docs can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/)

In short version you have to run command

`$ sudo kubeadm init`

After initialization you will receive information to run commands like:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

and token to join another VM to cluster. It looks like

```
kubeadm join 10.166.XX.XXX:6443 --token XXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX166b0b446986dd05c1334626aa82355e7
```

If you want to run some special action in init phase please check [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/).

**3. Change node status to `Ready`**

After previous step you will be able to execute

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS     ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ubuntu-kubeadm   NotReady   master   4m29s   v1.16.2
```

But your node will be in `NotReady` status. If you will describe it `$ kubectl describe node` you will see error:

```
Ready            False   Wed, 30 Oct 2019 09:55:09 +0000   Wed, 30 Oct 2019 09:50:03 +0000   KubeletNotReady              runtime network not ready: Ne
tworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

It means that you have to install one of CNIs. List of them can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

**EDIT**

Also one thing comes to my mind.

Sometimes when you turned off and on VM you need to restart 
kubelet and docker service. You can do it by using

```
$ service docker restart
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like kubeconfig file is missing.. Did you copy admin.conf file to ~/.kube/config ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if there are any proxies set like "http_proxy" or "https_proxy", mostly we set it as environment variables. If yes, then remove the proxies and it should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following 2 steps. The kubectl works now.

```
$ service docker restart
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```